# Standardizing variant post-test scores

Tags: standardization

I have been given a dataset with 7 groups of students each with 20 people in them. All 140 students completed the same pre-test before undergoing an education program - however each of the 7 groups had their own post-test. None of these tests had been used before (no idea of validity/reliability). Is there a statistical method of normalzing the post-test scores or creating a pre/post difference score that will allow me to conclude whether there had been an impact of the education program?